# How to access java.util.Arrays in painless script (elasticsearch)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to do a binary search on a huge array (sorted_keys)
`sorted_keys.length = 250,000`

```
my_script = f"""
         if (Arrays.binarySearch({sorted_keys}, doc['_meta.key'].value) > 0)) return 0; 
         return 1;
        """
        script = {"script": {"lang": "painless", "source": my_script }}
```

However this script gives me a compiling error,
`elasticsearch7.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'compile error')`

According to the docs it should be available
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/master/painless-api-reference-shared.html#_java_util

How can I use Arrays.binarySearch in painless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

binarySearch is available under `Collections` in painless unlike Java

so changing `Arrays` to `Collections` solved my problem